# Extension Methods. Error No overload for method 'WriteTextToConsole' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, this, extension-methods

I'm learning C# and C and this C# code is giving me an error I don't understand. I'm reading about extension methods and this code is giving the error: No overload for method 'WriteTextToConsole' takes 1 arguments. As you can see, it takes exactly 1 arguments? I created the variables c and count only to be able to construct the string object. So I could try the extension in the String class. Is it right understood that the way you create an extension method: is to precede the parameter with the "this" keyword and the parameter is of the type of class to be extended?

The code is here:

```
        Console.WriteLine();
        M.WriteTextToConsole("Hello, world. Programming in C# is fun");
        char c = 'A';
        int count = 14;
        String str = new String(c, count);
        str.WriteTextToConsole("This is a string");
```

The method is here:

```
static class M
{
  public static void WriteTextToConsole(this string text)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: The first argument is the string itself, `str` in your example. Your extension method needs two string arguments for this to compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to call it as `str.WriteTextToConsole();`. In this case `str` would be passed as a single argument to `M.WriteTextToConsole()` method

Answer (score 1):

When you call the extension method on the string the "this string text" parameter refers to the string itself,for example if it where "this Bitmap b" it would be an extension method for the bitmap and assuming you had created a bitmap object named `bit` the call would be `bit.WriteTextToConsole()`.If you want to had other parameters you need to add those to to the method declaration and to make so it is an option for the caller make it with the params keyword like so:

```
    static class M
    {
        public static void WriteTextToConsole(this string text,params string[] str)
        {
            if (str.Length > 0)
            {
                //do something with extra string or strings
                //you can make params Object[] but for this
                //example i choose string[]
                Console.WriteLine(text);
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
```

Just remenber the `this` keyword must be the first parameter,refering to the type you are extending.
In the case of having optional strings i left the code with the duplicate console.WriteLine(text) you can rewrite it if you in both cases want the string displayed in the console(just remove the return and console writeline above it).